# Is it possible Store literal VBA Variables into an Array?

Tags: vba, excel, office365, excel-2016

I have code that has a large series of pre-computed range variables. I'm looking to store those variables into an array where I can apply a loop. I don't want to have to re-declare some variable inside the loop as it is already declared elsewhere. However, I also do not want to duplicate my loop as the code is almost exactly the same.

```
Dim myarray(1) as variant, I as long, cell as range
'Some code that predetermines the needed variables. Type Range
myarray(0) = Rng1
myarray(1) = Rng2
for i = 0 to 1
    for each cell in myarray(i)
        'code to loop through cells
    next cell
next i
```

When I get to `for each cell in myarray(i)` I get `Run-time error '424': Object required`. Perhaps I am misunderstanding the purpose/use of an array. I can do this with other methods, but would require the re-declaration within the loop. As this bit of code is part of a much larger set of code and could mess up down the line, this is not the preferred option.

When I search this site or other sites, I find the phrase "Store variables into an array," but these are referring to pulling static values from a variable source such as a text file or some type reference to values stored in a sheet. I'm looking to store a literal variable of type range into it and be able to use it in a loop. Am I misunderstanding an array's declaration, calling, or perhaps it's general use?

Comment: `myarray(0) = Rng1` gets the values from the range, so probably `Set myarray(0) = Rng1`.

Comment: Thanks Slai, that ended up being part of the overall answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to overcome the error. One is either correcting the collection in for each loop and the other is correcting the array. Let us know which one worked for you.

**Method #1**: 
For Each loop requires a collection object unlike the string that you are passing. So, we will rather use string to get the range collection and then would loop over cells. Use the below code instead to overcome the error.

```
Dim myarray(1) as String, i as long, cell as range
'Some code that predetermines the needed variables. Type Range
myarray(0) = Rng1.Address
myarray(1) = Rng2.Address
For i = 0 to 1
    For Each cell in Range(myarray(i)).Cells
        'code to loop through cells
    next cell
Next i
```

**Method #2**:

```
Dim myarray(1) as Variant, i as long, cell as range
'Some code that predetermines the needed variables. Type Range
Set myarray(0) = Rng1
Set myarray(1) = Rng2
For i = 0 to 1
    For Each cell in myarray(i).Cells
        'code to loop through cells
    next cell
Next i
```

Comment: I tried Method 2 and it worked exactly as I expected. Thank you for your assistance! It was all in how I was setting the variables and using the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten it to just :

```
For Each cell in Union(Rng1, Rng2)
    'code to loop through cells
Next cell
```

---

*Update* : Separate method is often used for repeating code :

```
Sub method1(Range rng)
    ' code to loop through rng.Cells
End Sub
```

and sample conditional call in a separate method :

```
If someCondition Then method1(Rng1)
```

Comment: Hi Slai, Thank you for this answer. However, I don't think this option will work for me as the code to loop through cells is going to reference a different set of ranges depending on the initial range to loop through. That is why I was looking for the Array option to apply a formula to `i` so that depending on the initial loop, I can have the different ranges the code needs to apply to.